# how to set time delay between two frames in java

Tags: java

I am making a quiz using Java . I want user to get only 1 minute to answer the question.After 1 minute next question which is is next frame should be displayed . How can i do that without using threads?*

Answer (score 0):

try a Timer:

```
        int delay = 0;
        int period = 60000;
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                //jump to your next question
                });
            }
        }, delay, period);
```